Why Eloquent not throwing an error when there's a typo in column name?
When using a simple statement for creating an entry in a DB:
Post::create(['title_TYPO_HERE' => 'My awesome title']);

This will actually create a post with title = null (let's assume it's nullable)
How to make Eloquent fail in such cases to prevent typos?

it does not trigger an error bc this attribute is never sent to the database and the insert does not fail. Model operations will filter out attributes not defined in the $fillable attribute.

Thanks @krisgjika I'm aware of that, but IMO it would make sense to fail in case of typos. So I'm wondering if it's possible to configure Eloquent model somehow to do so.

https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/eloquent#configuring-eloquent-strictness should help you out. You can set the model to throw an exception on unfillable attributes.

Hmm, I wonder if it's possible too, but I suspect most use cases/approaches would prevent issues with typos in column names. Typically, you create the form for each column on the frontend, create a Request including validation for those form fields on the backend, then call Post::create($validatedInput), which, by that time, would naturally filter out your chances for a typo. Of course, hardcoding something like Post::create(['column_name' => 'value']) allows for typos galore, but this isn't typical. Sidenote, something like DB::table('...')->insert(...) would likely fail with typos.

what you are looking for seems to be: (https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/eloquent#configuring-eloquent-strictness)
class AppServiceProvider
{
  public function boot(): void
  {
    Model::preventSilentlyDiscardingAttributes(! $this->app->isProduction());
  }
}


Perfect, exactly what I needed, thank you @krisgjika!
